# Can I use VirtualEnv to install just some additional packages?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

If I am working on a shared web server with Python and some other packages like virtualenv already installed. Can I use virtualenv to install some additional packages I need in a specific directory while still using the system wide python and packages or better still can I just install the additional python packages in my own directory and use them for my website without requiring sudo permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly include all globally installed packages in your virtualenv with the  `--system-site-packages` switch:

> Give access to the global site-packages dir to the virtual environment

or disable global site packages with the `--no-site-packages` switch instead:

> Don't give access to the global site-packages dir to the virtual environment

The latter is currently the default.

I personally have `lxml` installed in my global site packages, so we can use that as a small demonstration:

```
$ virtualenv nositepackages
New python executable in nositepackages/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...c............done.
$ ./nositepackages/bin/python -c 'import lxml; print lxml.__package__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lxml
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages sitepackages
New python executable in sitepackages/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
$ ./sitepackages/bin/python -c 'import lxml; print lxml.__package__'
lxml
```

Comment: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#the-system-site-packages-option
This says I should have control over global site packages. Am I right to assume that they just mean the read permissions from packages available there? I want to have two site packages - one the global one which I can read and one local one which I can write to.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: exactly; when you create a virtualenv with `--system-site-packages` you get a local virtualenv into which you can install new packages to your heart's content. The *global* site packages is still available to you when using the python inside of the virtualenv, you can import from it, but you won't be writing to it.

Comment: what do I do if my version of virtualenv does not support this option and it is hard to get it updated?

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: In earlier versions the default was not to exclude the global site packages directory, and you had to use `--no-site-packages` switch instead to prevent that.

Comment: Oh ... I see ... I also figured I could just download the virtualenv latest script and download it to my directory.
One more question. What about syncing with the actual system site packages - when I run the script I get a copy of the system site packages but what if there are upgrades or new packages available system-wide how do I still get those?

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: newer versions don't do that anymore, no idea how to 'sync' in an older version, I'm afraid.

Comment: with the new version of the script as well it creates a symlink to the old version

Comment: If you want to change the `--system-site-packages` after creating a virtual environment, you can remove/rename the file 'lib/python2.7/no-global-site-packages.txt` (relative to the virtual env home - `cdvirtualenv` when it's active to get there.

Answer (score 0):

add a directory to $HOME named `lib` add a directory to that named `python`

add your new directory to your path/pythonpath .bashrc and .bash_profile

`nano ~/.bashrc` then add `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/lib/python` ,this sets up you environment when not accessed through the shell (eg through a website)

add same line to `.bash_profile` , this controls your environment when you log in through the shell

**logout of terminal and log back in**

`echo $PYTHONPATH` to make sure it has your ~/lib/python folder

download desired python package using `wget https://download` or `git clone package/repo`

if you downloaded a zip unzip it `tar -xvf somefile.tar.bz`

change to the directory where you unzipped it

`cd some_package\`

run setup.py with the --HOME tag

`python setup.py install --HOME=~`

test it

`python -c "import <package>;print <package>.VERSION;"`

congratulations you just installed custom packages :)

*On a Side note I find virtualenv to be a much more robust solution, however occasionally it can be hard to get properly setup.  this is just something if you only need a few custom packages...*

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just copy packages u need to the directory, for which you have permission. And then in the __init__.py you should modify python path this way:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/the_dir/with_packages")
```